# Building Stored Procedure for DB2 for IBM i (iSeries) through Data Studio fails

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-data-studio, db2-400

When trying to Deploy a Stored Procedure for DB2 on IBM i (an iSeries) through Data Studio, it says "No Build Services found for routine." in the status window.

I see options in preferences->Data Management->SQL Development->Routines->Deploy Options->SQL - External.  By default this is populated with Build utility name: DSNTPSMP, in SYSPROC schema, but that is not something that exists in iSeries.  Does anyone know the equivalent schema and program for that on an iSeries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting is for deploying to z/OS, not IBM i.  Generally speaking, an External SQL routine on IBM i is an HLL, like RPG or Cobol that you'd create separately, and then issue the SQL 'CREATE PROCEDURE' statement to register the program as a stored procedure to DB2 for i.